# Read only lines longer than a certain amount from .txt file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox, readline

I've been searching the net for a while trying to find out how to simply read only lines longer than 0 characters from a .txt file into a listbox in VB. I am using VS 2010 and want to read only lines that contain content into the list box.

For example I want to only read the lines labeled 1.

```
1
1


1
1

1
```

Comment: Thanks wasn't sure why it changed format after when I posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and LINQ:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Where(Function(x) x.Length > 0).ToList
```

To start at the 3rd line, use `Skip`:

```
IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Skip(2).Where(Function(x) x.Length > 0).ToList
```

Comment: Awesome that works but I need to start at the 3rd line so how would I enter a start line?

Comment: Also is there a way I could only read lines that start with a certain letter using this?? Or do I need to go about that another way??

Comment: @JoshuaCummings: sure, you can use `x.StartsWith("1")` instead of `x.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to add lines with text:

```
Dim notEmptyLines = From line In IO.File.ReadLines(path)
                    Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)

For Each line In notEmptyLines
    ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
Next
```

Replace `Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)` with `line.Length <> 0` if you also want to count  white-spaces.